# How to show placeholder in semantic-ui-vue dropdown without multiple attribute?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, dropdown, semantic-ui

I am using `semantic-ui-vue` dropdown and the `placeholder` option is not working if I don't use `multiple` attribute.

Here is my sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/mzppzqkwkp) .

I have placed 2 dropdowns:

1. Dropdown  without `multiple` attribute - **Placeholder not working**
2. Dropdown  with `multiple` attribute - **Placeholder working**

How to put placeholder in the 1st dropdown? In the same case, placeholder is working in their official [documentation](https://semantic-ui-vue.github.io/#/modules/dropdown).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

semantic-ui-vue requires the v-model value to be `null` in order to consider it "empty"

So, if you modify your code to instead of defaulting to an empty string `from: ""` you default to `from: null`